# Changing [[ORDERINFO]] in WooCommerce PDF invoice template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In the template for WooCommerce PDF invoices I see this piece of code `[[ORDERINFO]]`. There are others, all in double brackets. Some of the data outputted by these code is not needed on my invoices. So I want to customize it.

In particular, I don't need the Qty, Total ex., Tax (in the product line), the Price Inc and the Total Inc columns. I just need the Product and Price ex Column. Of course do I need the totalization on the invoice, as there is: Subtotal, VAT (if applicable) and Grand Total. Shipping is not needed because the products are all downloadable.

I really not know how and where I do that. Please advise.

Comment: Is the data you don't want within the `[[ORDERINFO]]` section, or one of the others you refer to?

Comment: If you would also indicate what data you do want, and what you don't want, on your invoice, that would help - the question is rather vague at the moment. I suspect, in any case, that [this documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks-and-filters-in-woocommerce-pdf-invoice/) will help.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I'm aware that it is a little vage. I see in the template.php file more code in double brackets. I don't need the Qty, Total ex., Tax (in the product line), the Price Inc and the Total Inc columns. I just need the Product an Price ex Column. Of course do I need the totalization on the invoice, as there is: Subtotal, VAT (if applicable) and Grand Total. Shipping is not needed because the products are all downloadable.

Comment: [This doc](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-pdf-invoice-setup-and-customization/) should also be useful. I don't know WooCommerce at all, so if you get stuck it won't be me that gives detailed advice, but please do try copying the template and playing around with the placeholders, as suggested by this new link. At present it is hard to know where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I think I can take som steps further with the link you provided. So, thank you for now.

Answer (score 0):

At classes directory there is a file called `class-pdf-send-pdf-class.php`. You can customize the component there. But I am not sure which part you have to customize to remove the Qty, Total and etc.

UPDATE
You can custom the order details from function `get_woocommerce_pdf_order_details`. Just edit the code inside `$line` and  don't forget to edit the `$header` inside `get_woocommerce_invoice_content` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I switched to another invoicing plugin. One of the reasons was that the plugin WooCommerce PDF invoices was not able to generate proper credit notes if needed. I went to https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/. Note that you need the Pro version in order to create credit notes. But it is the best invoicing plugin I found.